# Why am I unable to install AppImages on a brand new Kubuntu 18.04 install?

Tags: kubuntu, appimage

I've read about it, you're supposed to make it executable etc, and I have but double clicking it does not work. Trying to open it direct from CLI using `./appimagename*.AppImage` does not work either. I tried to open one for Etcher and it told me that libfuse was not available or something but when I looked that up and saw a response about needing to install it, I tried to install it and it said I already had the latest version.... so not really sure what's up with that?

Here are some examples of commands and their results:

```
david@TheWiz:~/Downloads$ sudo ./ocs*.AppImage
[sudo] password for david: 
sudo: ./ocs-store-3.3.0-1-x86_64.AppImage: command not found
```

Comment: Which Kubuntu version? Have you tried other AppImages besides Etcher? Where did you get the AppImage from?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the complete output of each attempt and failure. The exact command, and the complete error messages, in context, are very important. Summaries are generally too vague to be helpful.

Comment: https://bintray.com/probono/AppImages/download_file?file_path=Leafpad-0.8.18.1.glibc2.4-x86_64.AppImage made executable in Dolphin, double-clicked, works on Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I've updated my original question with the results of trying to install the OpenDesktop.org website application. The Leafpad example worked as intended. Etcher now seems to work but that could be because I have it installed on my machine via apt-get. 

also I think I just realized, AppImage is basically like a portable executable correct? It doesn't get registered to the KDE application list, correct? So I won't be able to see it in Software Center or Discover for easy uninstallation right? (tho I kno I can just delete the appimage, just want to see if there's a way to track it)

Comment: https://github.com/resin-io/etcher/releases/download/v1.4.4/etcher-electron-1.4.4-linux-x64.zip ... extracted the AppImage. It was already executable. Double-clicked in Dolphin. Worked.

Comment: I don't understand how you could install it using apt-get. Did you download a .deb file from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, that's what I  tried before. What about this  though? https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1175480/

Comment: Yes, their website has a link to some deb packages.

Comment: Hmmm so I think I fixed it. I downloaded the Appimaged app here: https://github.com/AppImage/appimaged  And it seems to be working as expected.